# Taking next item in a listbox (youtube videos) in c#

Tags: c#, axshockwaveflash

Just a quick question. How to take a next item in a listbox of c#? Just a simple code to go through the items in a listbox:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
  axShockwaveFlash1.Movie = (listBox1.Items[i].ToString());
}
```

But the problem is a last item is showing (youtube videos). How to automatically play next item when the previous ends?

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;

foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
{
    // Do stuff using "var" to represent the listbox item, I believe it comes out as a string.
    i++; // Increment i so we know what index we are at in the array.
}
```

Apologies, I may have misread the question. You wanted to make the next item play when the current item finishes? If so, take a look through the aShockwaveFlash1 object to try find a time remaining variable or similar.

Sorry if the first post wasted your time.